# What kinda construction 'everything else fails' is?

Tags: adverbs

We all have used it several times...

> When everything else fails try/do [something]

While going through the definitions, I came across this -

> [else](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/else?q=else) - *In addition; besides*

But then, if we go by books, **everything else** sounds ambiguous. If *everything* includes every single thing, what is ultimately **left** for being *else*?

Else=In addition/besides but in addition/besides what; as by putting the word *everything*, we have covered everything! How come something comes up when *everything* has already failed (in that example)?

Why not...

> When everything fails, try/do [something]

After Damkerng's useful comment, this also sounds a bit illogical! If *everything* fails, how can we come up with something? Everything has literally taken all the options!

How do we come up with such sentence?

Comment: I wonder, wouldn't you say the same thing or something very similar (with else) in your native language? (I know I do. Btw, I'm more used to *When all else fails, ...* Thanks to *G.I. Joe*.)

Comment: Yeah, included! This was surprise even in my mother-tongue ;) +1!

Comment: @DamkerngT. *all else fails* makes the question even deeper that other versions are also like this!

Comment: Small point about the title: when everything else _has_ failed, not _is_ failed :)

Comment: @oerkelens Oh yeah...thanks and corrected...but out of curiosity, is *is* there wrong?

Comment: I find "is failed" mostly with _failed_ being used as an adjective. (I saw a question that started with "Is failed IVF ....". The present perfect of _fail_ is, as far as I know, always formed with _have_.

Comment: See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117663/why-is-the-test-is-failed-acceptable) for the is/has failed part :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It still makes sense if we parse this:

> When everything **else** fails, do X.

to:

> When everything **[besides X]** fails, do X.

---

[For example:](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=everything%20else)

> I ordered the salad, since everything **else** on the menu had meat.

to:

> I ordered the salad, since everything on the menu **[besides the salad]** had meat.

Comment: That's cool. I also translated literally in my mother-tongue and it makes sense. +1 :) Thank you.

Comment: Can we explain "all else" this way?

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes; since "when all else fails" and "when everything else fails" basically mean the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the word else is the problem. English else is related with Latin alius/alia/aliud, an adjective meaning other. The combination everything else
means all other things (that are possible).

Comment: exactly, that's the *culprit* ;)

Comment: But *else* is relative to the thing now in focus.  You're ignoring the simple sense of "other" which requires, at a minimum, two things to be under scrutiny,  thing A and something that is not thing A.